# "client.read_holding_registers" Problem RTU pymodbus

Tags: python, pymodbus

i am trying to read temperature values from a PLC using pymodbus but it's not working.

## This is my code:

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
import logging

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='COM4',  baudrate=9600, timeout = 3, parity = 'N', stopbits=1,  bytesize=8)
connection = client.connect()
print(connection)

#request = client.read_holding_registers(1,1,unit=1)
request = client.read_holding_registers(40001, 1, unit=1)
print(request)
```

I tried to use the address 40001 and 1, but nether worked. I keep receving this message:

```
True
ModbusSerialClient(rtu baud[9600])
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Current transaction state - IDLE
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Running transaction 1
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:SEND: 0x3 0x3 0x9c 0x41 0x0 0x1 0xfb 0xac
DEBUG:pymodbus.client.sync:New Transaction state 'SENDING'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'SENDING' to 'WAITING FOR REPLY'
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Transaction failed. (Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)) 
DEBUG:pymodbus.framer.rtu_framer:Frame - [b''] not ready
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Getting transaction 3
DEBUG:pymodbus.transaction:Changing transaction state from 'PROCESSING REPLY' to 'TRANSACTION_COMPLETE'
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 2 bytes (0 received)
```

Comment: You are not getting any data back, this looks like a hardware issue. What hardware are you using to connect to your PLC (USB-to-RS485 or something else)? It might also be you are not targeting the right Unit ID, are you sure your PLC is slave ID number 1?

Comment: One more thing: with pymodbus you don't have to use the 4000x naming convention. When you call `read_holding_registers` the address argument should be 0 if you want to read holding register at address 40001. If you want to read register 40021 you need to subtract the offset (40001) to get 40021-40001=20, so you'd have to use 20 (0x14 in HEX) as the address argument.